# Uses Of a piece of and a slice of

Tags: measure-expressions

What's the difference between a piece of and a slice of, and when we use a piece of and a slice of for food and objects?

Comment: What did you find in the dictionary? Did you not notice that ***slice*** has a more "restricted" sense than ***piece*** (which I'd say is itself more "restricted" than ***part***). Partly that's because pieces can be any shape, but slices are usually cut from a loaf or a (circular) pie.

Comment: slice: "a thin, broad piece of food, such as bread, meat, or cake, cut from a larger portion."  Use "a slice of" when you have cut a slice.

Comment: Slices aren't only food though. Figurative uses include ***a slice of the action*** and ***a slice of the profits.*** Which latter is [at least as common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+slice+of+the+profits%2Ca+piece+of+the+profits&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) as ***a piece of the profits*** (but even added together they [don't come close](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+slice+of+the+profits%2Ca+share+of+the+profits&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) to ***a share of the profits***).

Comment: You should use a dictionary before asking here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

'Slice' as a *verb* is the action of cutting something cleanly with a knife. As a noun, a 'slice' of something means a piece that has been cut with knife. Pieces of foods which are normally apportioned this way, such as bread or cake, are often referred to as 'slices'. You could just as easily refer to these as 'pieces' (ie a 'piece of cake'), but the reverse would not be true - a piece of bread that had been roughly torn away from the loaf, as is often the tradition with some kinds of bread, could not rightly be called a 'slice', because it hasn't been sliced.

Other uses of 'slice' are *figurative*, and usually mean a *share* of something. In some cases where we might refer to a figurative 'slice' of something, 'piece' would not be correct. For example, "*a slice of the action*" is not uncommon, and would be interchangeable with "*a piece of the action*"; however, "*a slice of the profits*" would mean "*a share of the profits*".